# Unable to install Webrtc in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webrtc

I'm trying to install WebRtc in Visual Studio but so far has been unable to do it. either with Package Manager or Package Manager Console.

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

```
1. Open Visual Studio 2015
2. Select New project and select Asp web application ( either .NET framwork 4.5.1 or 4.5.2)
3. Install webrtc with this line on Package Manager Console : Install-Package XSockets.Sample.WebRTC
```

**What is the expected result?**

```
Webrtc should be install correctly
```

**What do you see instead?**

```
It says it has been installed but then it runs the roll back and removes all files that has just been installed.
```

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**

```
Visual Studio 2015.
Windows 8.1
```

Do anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebRTC sample package from XSockets is not updated to work in VS2015. Either use an earlier version of VS or just download the sample from github.

All the WebRTC code from XSockets  are open source on github.

[Sampleproject](https://github.com/XSockets/XVA/tree/master/XVA-05-01-WebRTCBasic)

[Source](https://github.com/XSockets/XSockets.WebRTC)

The WebRTC sample on nuget will probably be updated after the v5 release that will be out any day now.